# Jinja2 not loading template

Tags: html, python-3.x, jinja2

I was following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@jasonrigden/jinja2-templating-engine-tutorial-4bd31fb4aea3) and although I seem to doing everything correctly it is not able to find the template.

```
jinja
├── main.py
└── templates
    └── hello_world
```

This is the code in main.py

```py
from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader, Environment

file_loader = FileSystemLoader('templates')
env = Environment(loader=file_loader)
template = env.get_template('hello_world.txt')
output = template.render()
print(output)
```

> Error - jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: hello_world.txt

The error, I think, is at line 4, I already tried removing that *.txt* from the end but still getting the same error.

Please help me I have been trying to resolve this but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I do get the same error with `hello_world.txt` on line 5, but then, if I do  `template = env.get_template('hello_world')` it just works. are you sure you do not have a typo in your `templates` folder name?